# Translation of an employee/agent "abrir clave" in an insurance or real estate company?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I'm not sure what "abrir clave" in a company means?

Examples found in [Se prevé un gran desarrollo del seguro de Alquiler](http://www.pymeseguros.com/se-prev%C3%A9-un-gran-desarrollo-del-seguro-de-alquiler) :

> "Me sorprende que se diga que quieren canales profesionales y luego *abran clave* a una inmobiliaria."
>
> "Pero si alguien legalmente quiere *abrir clave* y cumple las condiciones, la compañía no se lo impide."

Another example found in [Conseguir claves en compañías](http://www.rankia.com/foros/seguros/temas/275264-conseguir-claves-companias) :

> "Re: Conseguir claves en compañías
>
> Y yo añadiría, aparte de conseguir la autorización y *abrir claves* [...] tiene alguna formación en materia de seguros?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en este contexto `clave` tiene el significado de "autorización, licencia o contrato de un agente dentro de una compañía".

En [el segundo link que enlazas](http://www.rankia.com/foros/seguros/temas/275264-conseguir-claves-companias) uno de los usuarios del foro (que parece especialmente profesional en el ramo) dice con respecto a `conseguir claves en compañías (Pelayo Liberty, Aviva, etc...)`

> Con respecto a las claves, las generalistas,se matan por **abrir un nuevo "punto de venta"**; si uno es realmente honesto e independiente ya no les hace tanta gracia pero con la crisis actual todo vale.

[Otro hilo del mismo foro](http://www.rankia.com/foros/seguros/temas/1436658-trabajar-como-corredor-seguros) dice

> También tienes que tener en cuenta la capacidad de producción que tienes ya que **las compañías quieren hacer rentables sus claves** y si tienes poca cartera en cada compañía, no serás nadie en ninguna y pasaran olímpicamente de ti, llegando incluso a rechazarte asegurar riesgo que a otros le permiten asegurar sin ningún problema o a **anularte la clave** pasando los clientes a **clave directa de sucursal** o a otro agente de la zona.

y finalmente en [este otro](http://www.rankia.com/foros/seguros/temas/1022355-puede-tener-codigo-colaboracion-compania-correduria-vez) respecto a `se puede tener código de agente en una compañía y a la vez colaborar también con una correduría asesorando para los dos sitios`

> Para más aclaración también se prohibe la actividad conjunta de varios agentes de seguros de tal forma que se simule el ejercicio como agente vinculado o como correduría, algo muy castizo en algunos ejemplares que **tienen claves a nombre del cónyuge, de los hijos, de la suegra y del perro para aparentar ser corredores** sin serlo con el grave perjuicio que pueden causar a su clientela

**Por tanto parece ser que las `claves` identifican a agentes dentro de compañías.** "Conseguir clave" en una compañía sería que te aceptasen como agente. la *jerga* sería "abrir clave". Por eso (como vemos en el primer ejemplo) "abrir clave" para estas compañías es "abrir un nuevo *punto de venta*", que es este nuevo corredor de seguros.

En el segundo ejemplo vemos que se llama `clave` al agente (o a la autorización del agente para representarlas). "Las empresas quieren hacer rentables sus claves", es decir, que el agente se haga rentable a través de vender muchos seguros.

Y finalmente en el tercero, donde se dice que "tienen claves a nombre de otros", parece ser que dice que algunos de estos agentes simulan tener a otros agentes o clientes (claves) en sus empresas.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca había escuchado **abrir llave**, posiblemente haga referencia a conseguir la habilitación o licencia para iniciar o abrir una compañía de seguros.
Saludos

Comment: La palabra en la pregunta is clave, no llave.